# Multiple figures title not appearing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am facing a problem with title disappearance for multiple figures in Matlab. However, for the first figure, the title doesn't disappear. For figure 2, it appears and disappears when its xlim command is executed.

The below code actually comes in for loop where I shift between the two figures for updating it. Since the actual code is very lengthy and truncating is not trivial, I have not put here. Any help on this highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

```
figure(1)
subplot(2,2,[1,2]);
title(['Comp. Domain-',num2str(N),' ','Elements',' ','wave-',wave,' ',num2str(steps), '/', num2str(length(st:inc:en)),' Steps'])
drawnow
figure(2)
subplot(2,2,[1,2]);
title(['Coefficients',' ','wave-',wave,' ',num2str(steps), '/', num2str(length(st:inc:en)),' Steps'])
drawnow
plot(AandB(1:steps,1),AandB(1:steps,2),'-*r') % hbyL Vs
xlim([0 en])
%     ylim([-1 1])
xlabel('Non-Dimensional Number (hbyL)')
ylabel('C_a')
set(get(gca,'ylabel'),'rotation',0)
subplot(2,2,[3,4]);
plot(AandB(1:steps,1),AandB(1:steps,3),'-*b') % omega Vs adab
xlim([0 en])
%     ylim([0 2.5])
xlabel('Non-Dimensional Number (hbyL)')
ylabel('C_d')
set(get(gca,'ylabel'),'rotation',0)
```

Comment: It's the `plot` function that is removing the title, not the `xlim`.  By default the `plot` function clears the current axis (which is where the title is stored) and hence the title no longer exists.  You can either use `hold on`, or `hold all` to change the behaviour, or use a lower level plotting function such as `line`.

Comment: Dear @PhilGoddard, Thanks a lot for the reply. It worked nicely.